# How do I recover a partition table?

Tags: partition-recovery

How do I recover a partition table? I have an old disk that I found and I am sure there was data on it. I think the partition table was cleared, but I want to know if I can recover any data.

Answer (score 0):

Use TestDisk. This will recover your partition table and can also partially rebuild some parts of many filesystems. It works on Linux, Mac, Windows, DOS, and BSD systems.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk